# Resizing UILabel with no quality loss

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I want to be able to resize a UILabel using a `UIPinchGesture`, with no quality loss. At the moment I can resize it though it becomes really blurry.

Here is my Code

```
label = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0,100,300,50))
    label.text = "Hellow World"
    label.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: self.label.frame.height)
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    self.resizeRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleScale:"))
    self.rotateRecognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleRotate:"))

    label.userInteractionEnabled = true
    label.addGestureRecognizer(self.resizeRecognizer)
```

This is my gesture recogniser

```
func handleScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
{
    recognizer.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view!.transform,
        recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
    recognizer.scale = 1
        recognizer.view!.frame = CGRectMake(recognizer.view!.frame.minX, recognizer.view!.frame.minY, recognizer.view!.frame.width, recognizer.view!.frame.height)

    println(recognizer.view!.frame)
    println(self.label.font.fontWithSize(recognizer.view!.frame.height))
    println(self.label.frame)

}
```

What needs to happen here is when the labels frame is scaled, the size of the text also need to change as well. 
So as I change the frame the font size should change `label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: self.label.frame.height)`

This is what I have come to

```
<UICTFont: 0x7ffb39e17ba0> font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 578.77pt
<UICTFont: 0x7ffb3ca03ed0> font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 594.29pt
```

The font size does adjust as the frame adjusts, I have tried making that the font size from the beginning and it renders crisp.
What I think is going on is, the actual label isn't getting re rendered again.
Does anybody know what's going on or how to fix it?

Edit:

The text on the top is what I want to happen after rescale, the text on the bottom is what is happening

[image: Top = Correct, Botton = Incorrect]

The way I achieved this was I created a new label with the sizing of the old label then added it to the subview, I want to be able to do this upon rescaling, if that makes any sense

Comment: Try setting the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth' property of the UILabel to true, and don't change the font size manually.

Comment: @gabuh label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true; doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are not updating the font size, fontWithSize returns a font that you should assign to the label.

```
  func handleScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
{
    self.test.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.test.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
    recognizer.scale = 1


    println(recognizer.view!.frame)


    self.test.font = self.test.font.fontWithSize(recognizer.view!.frame.height)
    println(self.test.font)
    println(self.test.frame)


}
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't change the label font size.

Comment: the problem with this solution is: when you are setting the new bigger font *and scaled transform*, it will either make font bigger and apply transformation to it, and you will end up having still blurred text, which is scaled twice as fast. You should really *only change the font size* when scaling. @sameh's answer looks promising to me

Answer (score 0):

Create a UILabel with a font size that fits in your maxiumum zoom scale. Then use the transform property to scale it to its initial size. Also, set adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to false.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried coding it but I don't get what you mean by "Then use the transform property to scale it to its initial size"

Comment: Say your UITextField height should be 50 points initially and you want to be able to scale it up to at most 500 points height. First you need to find the font size that matches a height of 500 points (by trial and error). Then you set the frame height to 500 and its width to the width of the content (e.g. using the sizeThatFits or sizeToFit method). Finally scale the text field using the transform property: `textField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( 0.1, 0.1)`.

Comment: Ok, I just coded it, when the label is at its initial size it is still blurry until you scale it back up.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code and did figure out that, above code just update label frame. Actually font size is not updating as you expected.

Follow below code and you can clearly see the differences.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var resizeRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer!
    var rotateRecognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer!
    var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(50,300,300,50))
        label.text = "Hello World"
        label.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        self.resizeRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer()
        self.resizeRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleScale:"))
        label.userInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(self.resizeRecognizer)
    }

    func handleScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
    {
        recognizer.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view!.transform,
            recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
        recognizer.scale = 1
        recognizer.view!.frame = CGRectMake(0, recognizer.view!.frame.minY, recognizer.view!.frame.width, recognizer.view!.frame.height)

        label.frame = CGRectMake(recognizer.view!.frame.minX, recognizer.view!.frame.minY, recognizer.view!.frame.width, recognizer.view!.frame.height)
        label.font = UIFont(name: self.label.font.fontName, size: recognizer.view!.frame.height)

        // Or Suggested solution
        var fontSize = CGFloat(recognizer.view!.frame.height / 2)

        label.font = UIFont(name: self.label.font.fontName, size: recognizer.view!.frame.height - fontSize)

    }
}
```

Comment: @Johno2110: Check this answer and see the result.

Comment: I have placed this in my code, it is the closest I have come yet, but the text doesn't transform in relation to the frame, if you scale it to large the text disappears. What I want to be able to achieve is when the frame is scaled but have the text non blurry.

Comment: I have check that text is non blurry. And If you see the grey lines at border of text than it is default shadow color of text.

Comment: I know your method doesn't produce blurry text but the scaling doesn't really work and when scaled to much the text disappears

Comment: Here label height is proportional to height of label and font point size behaviour is different I mean for different fonts it's size react differently. How ever check edited answer, I have mention one more solution but if we decrease ratio it will then going to be blurry.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let label = UILabel()
let pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.text = "first line\nsecond line"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Menlo-Regular", size: 25)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    pinchRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "changeFontSize")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer)
}

func changeFontSize() {

    if pinchRecognizer.state == .Began {

        pinchRecognizer.scale = label.font.pointSize * 0.1
    }

    if 1 <= pinchRecognizer.scale && pinchRecognizer.scale <= 5  {

        let cent = label.center
        label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: pinchRecognizer.scale * 10)
        label.frame.size.width = 999
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.center = cent 
    }
}


}
```